# compiled wget for linux webserver

Tags: linux, 64-bit, wget, redhat, compiled

how do i get a compiled wget for one of my server 
Linux version 2.6.18-028stab070.5 (root@rhel5-build-x64) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46))

i dont have root privilege, so cant compile wget source on the server

Comment: Why can you not ask someone that *does* have root to install it?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need root privileges to compile and execute ordinary programs, unless someone's done something nasty such as put your home directory on a non-executable file system.

What you may be running into is a system of packages (for either wget or build tools like gcc) that assumes you want to install programs in system directories for all users, rather than under your home directory for yourself.  But that's a problem with the packaging, not a fundamental limitation of gcc or of what an unprivileged user can do.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the rpm and extract it manually using `rpm2cpio` and `cpio`.